# Twitter Typeahead.js, `suggestionsRendered` event callback, how do I get the suggestions data?

Tags: events, autocomplete, typeahead.js, twitter-typeahead

#### How can I hook into the `suggestionsRendered` event of Twitter's Typeahead and access the filtered data so I can update my table using this data?

I am using `Twitter Bootstrap 3`, this version has moved the `typeahead` plugin into its own library, and the old typeahead plugin is no longer being maintained.

I have setup typeahead to work as I would like, but I have an issue where I would like the library to fire a callback once `suggestionsRendered` has fired internally.

Attaching events via the normal fashion does not work, the only events *currently* available are located here: https://github.com/twitter/typeahead.js#custom-events

- `typeahead:initialized` *(fired when the typeahead has loaded (and prefetched data))*
- `typeahead:opened` *(fired when the typeahead suggestion box opens)*
- `typeahead:closed` *(fired when the typeahead suggestion box closes)*
- `typeahead:selected` *(fired when a suggestion is selected)*
- `typeahead:autocompleted` *(fired on tab press, or whenever autocompleted)*

You can use the above events like so:

```
// This is how you use the above events.
$searchTypeahead.on('typeahead:selected',function(evt,data){
    console.log('typeahead:selected');
    console.log(data); // Contains the selected items data
});
```

---

#### **The Problem**

As someone is typing in the input field, I want to update the rows inside a table, I can't use none of the above events to update a table as I type (They only work for clicks, selections, hovers etc..).

How can I retrieve the filtered data that `suggestionsRendered` renders? (So instead of rendering it into the typeahead box, I want to access all the items, so I can loop over them, and add them into a table).

*I've tried googling (listed for SEO): (but find information related to the old (and unmaintained) version of typeahead)*

twitter bootstrap 3 typeahead suggestionsRendered custom event
twitter bootstrap 3 typeahead suggestionRendered custom event
twitter bootstrap 3 typeahead suggestionsRendered callback
twitter bootstrap 3 typeahead suggestionsRendered get data callback

*Finally.. I found a thread on github that states this feature has been requested and is waiting to be implemented (though this comment was from 10 months ago).*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Currently this feature is waiting to be implemented (along with a bunch of other callbacks), I have found a simple solution (which requires editing the core `typeahead.js` library)

#### Step 1

Inside `typeahead.js` find the following line *(approx `Line: 840` in `v0.9.3`)*.

```
// Within Class DropdownView
renderSuggestions: function(dataset, suggestions) {
...
    this.trigger("suggestionsRendered"); // Find this line! approx line: 840
...
}
```

#### Step 2

Change the above line to:

```
renderSuggestions: function(dataset, suggestions) {
...
    this.trigger("suggestionsRendered", suggestions); // Pass "suggestions" var
...
}
```

#### Step 3

Finally in your `HTML` page (or `Javascript` file), use the following to attach the `event`:

```
// When you initialize your typeahead, store it into a variable
$typeahead = $('#your-typeahead-input-id-or-class').typeahead({options});

// Access that elements data property, and attach the event to dropdownView
$typeahead.data('ttView').dropdownView.on('suggestionsRendered', function (evtObj) {
    console.log(evtObj.type); // Holds the event type: "suggestionsRendered"
    console.log(evtObj.data); // Holds results of filtered data: Object
    console.log("suggestionsRendered event callback fired");
    // Do your stuffs..
});
```

---

### Thats it!

#### If you log the `evtObj` var, you will have the event type AND data! :)

Answer (score 1):

I believe this example for dealing with events is more relevant now: https://github.com/twitter/typeahead.js/issues/300